# How to update text of a specific line on terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm programming bash script but there is a problem that is how to update text of a specific line.

I've tried using **clear** command. But using **clear** is refresh all lines on terminal but i want to refresh specific line. Like under

===============

TIME: 20:35

===============

I want to refresh only "20:35" part, without "=====" and "TIME:".

1)

```
while true
do
clear
echo "
===============
TIME: $(date +%H:%M)
==============="
done
```

2)

```
function TIME_RE(){
while true
do
printf "TIME: $(date +%Y.%m.%d) ($(date +%H:%M:%S)) \r"
done
}
echo "
===============
TIME: $(TIME_RE)
==============="
```

I expected result of second is refreshing only "**$(TIME_RE)**" part, but it displayed nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to move cursor position, or save and restore cursor position. For example, using the cursor up sequence:

```
while true; do
echo -e "
===============
TIME: $(date +%Y.%m.%d) ($(date +%H:%M:%S))
===============
\e[5A"
sleep 1
done
```

Notes:

- you need echo's `-e` option to let you print escape sequences.
- the "\e[5A" is the sequence to move 5 lines up.
- add something like "sleep 1" as delays to avoid burdening the system.

Comment: I will try to use something like this for a terminal game :) Thanks!